# How to get selected header label from QTableWidget item?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` item. I fill this item with pandas `DataFrame` data. I must print selected column values as a report. I can easily print data from DataFrame. However, I need to know `verticalHeader` (`QTableWidget`) labels to get data from 'DataFrame'. How can I get selected header labels from `QTableWidget`?

I tried `QTableWidget.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()` and `QTableWidget.itemFromIndex()` method. I could only get items inside of the table not header labels.

Here is my table. I can get items under 'Product No', 'Product Option' and 'List Price (USD)' headers but I can't get these headers.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `QTableWidget.verticalHeaderItem()` with the table's current row. If the selected cells are all in the same row, you could do this (`table` refers to the QTableWidget).

```
row = table.currentRow()
label = table.verticalHeaderItem(row).text()
```

Or if cells are selected over multiple rows:

```
rows = set(cell.row() for cell in table.selectedIndexes()) # set to remove duplicates, otherwise use a list
labels = [table.verticalHeaderItem(r).text() for r in rows]
```

In the case that a row does not contain a vertical header item, use the `text()` method only after you've checked that item returned is not None.

```
headers = [table.verticalHeaderItem(r) for r in rows]
labels = [x.text() for x in headers if x is not None]
```

**Edit:** Those are *horizontal* header items, not vertical. In that case use `table.horizontalHeaderItem()` instead and get cell columns.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

Comment: @Ugurcan That's probably because there was no vertical header in a particular row. I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you. I am new at PyQT and QT. 
It worked.

´columns = set(cell.column() for cell in self.table.selectedIndexes())  # set to remove duplicates, otherwise use a list
labels = [self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(c).text() for c in columns]´